# Search and cut contour Opencv C #

Tags: c#, opencv

It is necessary to cut an object by photo using a mask and blur the edges.
Code to search for edges. But what about the blur?

```
Mat imgGray = new Mat();    
Cv2.CvtColor(segmentationMap, imgGray, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY, 0);
Cv2.Blur(imgGray,imgGray, new Size(3,3));

Mat imgCanny = new Mat();
Cv2.Canny(imgGray,imgCanny, 2, 3);

Point[][] contours;
HierarchyIndex[] hierarchy;

Cv2.FindContours(imgCanny, out contours, out hierarchy, RetrievalModes.Tree, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxSimple);

Mat drawing  = new Mat(imgCanny.Size(), MatType.CV_8UC3);

for (int i = 0; i < contours.Length; i++)
{
     Scalar color = Scalar.Red;
     Cv2.DrawContours(drawing,contours, i, color);
}
```

1. Paint the area inside the contour.
2. Cut by mask
3. Blur the edges

Mask

[image]

Contour (But he is not closed for some reason)

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Please explain what you've tried and what's currently not working.

Comment: I do not know how to combine the mask and image. Except per pixel pass. Blur edges think about it

Comment: Set last row of the mask 0 before findContours.

Comment: @Nuzhny I do not understand where. I still need to mask the image and blur the edges.

Comment: After Cv2.Blur call:  imgGray.GetRow(imgGray.Width - 1).SetTo(imgGray.);

Comment: @Nuzhny Mat not metod GetRow

Comment: Ok. You can draw a black line: imgGray.Line(pt1, pt2, Scalar.Black, 1, ...). Where pt1(0, imgGray.Height - 1) and pt2(imgGray.Width - 1, imgGray.Height - 1)

Comment: @Nuzhny Thanks, but this was not a problem. You need to cut the image and blur the outlines.